# Cordova Cocoapods - Apple on demand resources

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods, on-demand-resources

I have a Cordova application but I am struggling when building my IOS project. My application contains a lot of zip files that are not needed on app load. So I am using apple ODR for these resources. The problem is I don't want to use xcode to tag these resources manually. As the xproject files are only created after platform add. In comes cocoapods.

I want to create a pod that is local to my project that is installed with 'cordova platform add ios" + cordova build ios'. I was hoping to do something like this, As cocoapods supports on-demand resources.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = 'assets'
  spec.version = '1.0'

  spec.on_demand_resources = {
    'ZipFile' => ['/content/files/*']
  }
end
```

Just looking for advice if this is a good way to achieve this or if anyone has other experience with cocapods + on demand resources.